# NPM throws errors at traceur install on OS X

Tags: node.js, git, gruntjs, npm, traceur

https://github.com/tejas-manohar/itnerary-civic-hacking -- I cloned this git repo down locally. Installed grunt-cli globally, and ran `npm run nss` (script written by author of original server template -- look in package.json, not complex) and faced numerous errors at the traceur install + git cloning. I've included the trail from terminal window in the pastebin linked below. The npm debug/error log mentioned is not present at the suggested location. `npm install` alone does not help the situation and returns nothing back. NodeJS v0.10.29 is installed via Node Version Manager (NVM) on OS X 10.9.3.

http://pastebin.com/UJFL3k2E

I'm not the most adept with some of the technologies discussed here. Would someone please attempt to walk me through (a) solution(s) and/or steps to get better clues? All assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of problems going on which are causing the problems you have seen.  The first of which is the command that is run when you run `npm run nss`, which fails for you with this:

> rm: ../../app/static/js/vendor/traceur.js: No such file or directory

This is because, well, the file simply does not exist (yet).  If you look at the commands which are run when you run `npm run nss`, you'll see that the remove file is followed by the copy file of `traceur.js` to that very location.  So I would guess that whoever wrote the script intended for this to be run after it was initially setup, and the remove/copy would be done once the file was initially copied there.  Therefore, you must first copy the `traceur.js` file to `app/static/js/vendor` before you can successfully execute `npm run nss`.

But then the next problem, the file should be copied from `tools/traceur-compiler/bin` doesn't exist either.  This is because the traceur-compiler project has recently deleted this (compiled) file from their project, which you can see via this commit: https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler/commit/429c3d850dcb7636320e81fd782c61a06de0fbf1

So you need to regenerate this file, which you can do by (from the `itnerary-civic-hacking` root directory):

- `cd tools/traceur-compiler`
- `make bin/traceur.js`
- `cp bin/traceur.js ../../app/static/js/vendor`

This will get you in the same state as if you successfully ran `npm run nss`.

You won't be able to re-run the `npm run nss` command, but you really shouldn't need to since its more of a setup command than anything (it creates a directory, clones a github repo, etc).  If you wanted to update the `traceur-compiler` in the future (though you may never have to do this) then I would recommend running the following steps (from the `itnerary-civic-hacking` root directory):

- `cd tools/traceur-compiler`
- `git pull origin master`
- `npm install`
- `make bin/traceur.js`
- `cp bin/traceur.js ../../app/static/js/vendor`

Comment: I might've actually marked this as best answer too soon, but I'm confident you'll be able to respond again adequately in the comments. `fatal: destination path 'tools/traceur-compiler' already exists and is not an empty directory.` is the result of running `npm run nss` after the steps you advised at the git clone step...

I tried deleteing tools/traceur-compiler but then the original issue occurred. Any advice? If you're feeling generous, you can even submit a pull request to fix this on the repo but an explanation + solution is necessary for best answer :)

Comment: also, guessing that no uninstalls are needed since this is all locally in the project directory. please confirm

Comment: @tejas-manohar Sorry, you're right, the `npm run nss` won't work, but shouldn't have to be run again (I've updated the answer to include this).  And no, you shouldn't have to uninstall anything since everything is local to the directory.

Comment: so what would I need to alter the 'nss' script to in order to get the repo work after cloning into a machine with grunt-cli installed globally?

Comment: I haven't seen any need to change anything related to grunt. I'm not sure what the original intention was with the nss script. It appears to be both a setup and an update script. The setup should clone the repo, then run the steps I've outlined above (but not remove any file since it doesn't exist yet). The update should do the steps I've stated above (for update). It really depends on what you want to do.

Comment: also, for some reason, the google map is not showing up for me, but it was about 3 weeks ago, i ran grunt in the project directory and got the following -- http://pastebin.com/hJCnrHii --> maybe you know a solution for this major issue now? you're really the only one responding and have provided a ton of help so best answer :)

Comment: Great, glad things are moving along :)  I would recommend posting a separate question for any other problems you may have.

Comment: ok, will do and tag it here, im not really sure if things are working as they were supposed to though, because the map is not working which could be a result of traceur not being installed properly so still no verification here :)